Is ICL Surgery Approved by DGCA in India?
In India, my physical doesn't look like a good fit for Laser Assisted in Situ Keratomileusis, LASIK, but I am considering the Implantable Collamer Lens, ICL. I am not sure if the ICL be approved by the Directorate General of Civil Aviation, DGCA, in India. Where can I find related information?
